# How to join a DataFrame with itself, and aggregate

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm having trouble understanding how to join a `DataFrame` with itself, and reference the left and the right side of the join specifically in `Column` conditionals. I thought that `Dataset.alias` was sufficient, but I must be wrong, or there must be some other deficiency in my understanding. To illustrate:

Given a DataFrame like:

```
val people = Seq((1,"foo",11),(2,"foo",12),(3,"bar",23),(4,"bar",24),(5,"bar",25),(6,"zap",36)).toDF("id","group","number")
people.show()
// +---+-----+------+
// | id|group|number|
// +---+-----+------+
// |  1|  foo|    11|
// |  2|  foo|    12|
// |  3|  bar|    23|
// |  4|  bar|    24|
// |  5|  bar|    25|
// |  6|  zap|    36|
// +---+-----+------+
```

If I would like to know how many entries there are per group for any given id, I might do:

```
val others = people.alias("others")
val peopleInGroup = (
  people
    .join(others, people("group") === others("group"), "left_outer")
    .groupBy(people("id"))
)
peopleInGroup.count().show()
// +---+-----+
// | id|count|
// +---+-----+
// |  1|    2|
// |  6|    1|
// |  3|    3|
// |  5|    3|
// |  4|    3|
// |  2|    2|
// +---+-----+
```

Its a little concerning that the order of ids has changed, but the count values are what I would expect; so far so good.

If I would like to know how many other entries there are per group, I might do:

```
val othersInGroup = (
  people
    .join(others, people("group") === others("group"), "left_outer")
    .filter(people("id") =!= others("id"))
    .groupBy(people("id"))
)
othersInGroup.count().show()
// +---+-----+
// | id|count|
// +---+-----+
// +---+-----+
```

, which is not what I expect. I would expect:

```
// +---+-----+
// | id|count|
// +---+-----+
// |  1|    1|
// |  3|    2|
// |  5|    2|
// |  4|    2|
// |  2|    1|
// +---+-----+
```

To take a slightly less trivial example:

```
val otherWithLowerNumber = (
  people
    .join(others, people("group") === others("group"), "left_outer")
    .filter(people("number") > others("number"))
    .groupBy(people("id"))
)
otherWithLowerNumber.count().show()
// +---+-----+
// | id|count|
// +---+-----+
// +---+-----+
```

I would expect:

```
// +---+-----+
// | id|count|
// +---+-----+
// |  5|    2|
// |  4|    1|
// |  2|    1|
// +---+-----+
```

It seems to me that I'm missing what is needed to distinguish between `people.values` and `other.values`. How can I do this?

I am using Spark 2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you use equi-joins you should alias for both tables and reference columns with their fully qualified names:

```
import spark.implicits._

people.alias("people") 
  // Equi-join by name could be replaced with
  // $"people.group" === $"others.group"
  .join(others, Seq("group"), "left_outer") 
  .where($"people.id" =!= $"others.id")
  .groupBy($"people.id")
  .count
```

```
+---+-----+
| id|count|
+---+-----+
|  1|    1|
|  3|    2|
|  5|    2|
|  4|    2|
|  2|    1|
+---+-----+
```

Without aliases conditions like `people("id") =!= others("id")` or `people("id") > others("id")` are considered to be trivially false, hence the results.